# file_exsists not working php

Tags: php

I have this problem:
    $id is id for each user

```
$img = 'http://www.somesite.com/pictures/';
$no_img = 'http://www.somesite.com/pictures/default.jpg';
$slika_provera = "{$img}{$id[$i]}/t_1.jpg";
if (file_exists($slika_provera)){
    $slika = $slika_provera;
} else {
    $slika = $no_img;    
}
```

And this loop always set `$slika = $no_img` no matter if the file exists or not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does $slika_provera output? Use var_dump($slika_provera);

Comment: also, $img has to be either relative to the main php file or absolute. Please check.

Comment: There's a lot of variables in that expression; what's `var_dump($img, $id, $id[$i]);`

Comment: $slika_provera is path to the image. I use absolute path to all images. $no_img is default image if specific image is not set.

Comment: I share the above posters sentiments: You should make sure that the variables that you work with in that string actually are what you expect them to be. For instance, is the array $id really populated at index $i? Maybe you should just `echo $slika_provera` ever so often in your loop …

Comment: `$img='http://www.somesite.com/pictures/';` is not a valid path for file_exists... Should be something along the lines of `/var/www/somesite.com/pictures/`

Comment: I've echo $slika_provera and it's good path

Comment: Only thing I don't understand is why I get so many minuses. I wouldn't ask a question if I already know the answer. Pluses and minuses for answer  I understand but minuses for question... Obiusly some people don't have anything else to do and they are so smart so they need to give me the minus for answer.

Comment: The main reason is that it would have taken a few moments to Google this and you'd have found an answer either on stackoverflow or in the PHP manual already... (I was not one of the down-votes). Lesson to learn - show that you have tried to help yourself before asking and you will get a better response!

Comment: Brian thanks for being honest. Your answer make me change my view of + and - on stack. I didn't look at this that way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function file_exists() does not work with URL's.

Have a look at the *manual* for file_exists() for methods to do equivalent for URL's: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php in particular I use this approach: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#76420